# How does IIS7 handle low memory?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

Does anyone know what responses a IIS7 server (running on Windows Server 2008) will send if the memory spikes?

Will it just start Timing out, will it start to send responses saying that it is currently unavaliable or will it say that it cannot handle the load.

The question is kind of akward but does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the application pool settings that determine the maximum amount of memory an application can use.  If the application exceeds this limit the pool may recycle, causing whatever web application run in it to also restart and droping/losing sessions along the way.